# Automating Isopleths in GME?

Tags: kernel-density, gme

Is there an easy way to batch generate isopleths in GME?

I have a set of 109 different kernel density estimates that I need to make 50% and 95% isopleths for, but in the interest of saving time and not having to do them all one at a time I would like to be able to automate the process. I am new to using GME so I have been looking over the GME manual and some tutorials found online, but nothing was apparent to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is "raster.vol" function in R library spatialEco that returns a percent volume (isopleth) for a probability/density raster. Unlike the GME isopleth command, that returns contours, this function returns a binary raster where 1 represents the Nth percent volume.

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)
  r <- raster(ncols=100, nrows=100)
    r[] <- runif(ncell(r), 0, 1)
    r <- focal(r, w=focalWeight(r, 6, "Gauss"))
    r[sample(1000, 1:ncell(r))] <- NA

  # full raster percent volume 
  p30 <- raster.vol(r, p=0.30)
  p50 <- raster.vol(r, p=0.50)
  p80 <- raster.vol(r, p=0.80)
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    plot(r, col=cm.colors(10), main="original raster")
    plot(p30, breaks=c(0,0.1,1), col=c("cyan","red"), legend=FALSE,
      main="30% volume")
    plot(p50, breaks=c(0,0.1,1), col=c("cyan","red"), legend=FALSE,
      main="50% volume")
    plot(p80, breaks=c(0,0.1,1), col=c("cyan","red"), legend=FALSE,
      main="80% volume")
```

You could easily loop this function over a series of rasters.

Here we create some example data.

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)
r <- raster(ncols=100, nrows=100)
  r[] <- runif(ncell(r), 0, 1)
  r <- focal(r, w=focalWeight(r, 6, "Gauss"))
s <- brick(r)
  for(i in 1:5) {
    r[] <- runif(ncell(r), 0, 1)
    s <- addLayer(s, focal(r, w=focalWeight(s[[i]], 6, "Gauss")))
  }
```

Your rasters can be read into a stack object, suitable for the next step, using list.files and the raster package's stack/brick function. The below syntax uses a wildcard to list all "tif" format rasters in the specified directory.

```
# s <- stack(list.files("C:/mydata", "tif$", full.names = TRUE))
```

We can then create a stack with the same dimensions a the stack containing the density rasters and run the raster.vol function on each raster.

```
s50 <- s
for(i in 1:nlayers(s)) { s50[[i]] <- raster.vol(s[[i]], p=0.50) }
```

You can then use writeRaster to write a multiband raster with the densities or loop through each raster in the stack.